# XDebug Speed - Why is it so slow (v2.6.2 -> 2.8.0b2)

Tags: xdebug

What is going on with XDebug's speed recently? I've benchmarked the following versions - all running the same page (a mature Symfony 2 app, so not a simple request by any means) and it appears that since version 2.7 it got worse and then even more so when it disabled the ZendOPCache in 2.7.2.

- 2.8.0b2 - 22.3 seconds
- 2.7.2 - 6.9 seconds
- 2.7.0 - 4.8 seconds
- 2.6.1 - 2.3 seconds

(All on the same hardware, performed by simply switching the version of XDebug being used)

Naturally without XDebug enabled the page runs fine (0.7seconds), but using the latest versions (and I appreciate 2.8.0 is a beta), its getting on for unusable.

This is my config I used for the test

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.var_display_max_children=512
xdebug.var_display_max_data=32000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=8
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdbg.log
```

I then found a few more tips and this knocked off a little, but we're talking a few ms across all versions.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=512
xdebug.var_display_max_data=32000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=12
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdbg.log
xdebug.profiler_enable=0

xdebug.collect_includes = 0
xdebug.collect_params = 0
xdebug.collect_return = 0
xdebug.collect_vars = 0


xdebug.overload_var_dump = 2

xdebug.coverage_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

Am I just missing something or is it simply XDebug is getting slow these days?

Comment: Tired of waiting 20-25s per request to Xdebug a WordPress/TypeRocket app, I just tried versions 2.9 and 2.8 (both equally slow), 2.7.2 (~17s) and 2.6.1 (~14s).  Not as dramatic as yours (it figures, with WP), but still a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't disable OPcache. It's a great performance boost.

As to Xdebug slowing things down, it's hard to say why it does that without knowing the full application. If you're not using Code Coverage, then setting [`xdebug.coverage_enable=0`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#coverage_enable) is a good idea.

Many of the settings that you show to "knock a few things off" are basically the default, so they won't do a lot. If you can easily provide a reproducible case, then I would suggest you file a bug at https://bugs.xdebug.org so that Xdebug's author can have a look at it, but only really if it's easy to reproduce.

Xdebug does disable some OPcache settings. And this depends on the PHP version. Only for 7.3.0 and 7.3.1 to we turn off a specific optimisation always, and for later versions, OPcache *optimisations* (but not OPcache itself) are turned off when `xdebug.remote_enable=1`: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/xdebug.c#L1086-L1103 — this should have some impact, but not as much as you indicate.

I'm curious to find out though, as I want to make things go faster, and not slower :-)

Comment: You misunderstand, XDebug disabled OPCache in 2.7.2 due to a bug / issue with it when stepping through code, if I recall correctly, its not something I've done. Disabling OpCache is probably the main reason for the slow down.

Comment: That depends on the PHP version though. Only for 7.3.0 and 7.3.1 to we turn off a specific optimisation always, and for later versions, OPcache *optimisations* (but not OPcache itself) is turned off when `xdebug.remote_enable=1`: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/xdebug.c#L1086 — I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah ok - I'm on PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu, btw, if it helps. But I've had to go back to 2.6.1 as the performance drop off on the more complicated pages is 20+ seconds between 2.7.2 and 2.6.1. Luckly we only run into a seg fault with 2.6.1 on one particular page (for some reason), so I can switch to 2.7.2 if I need to for that one!

If there's anyway I can help (debug builds etc..) please let me know, I'm more than happy to help.

(Oh and sorry for telling you what XDebug did in 2.7.2, I didn't realise you were the author!) lol

Comment: @Derick 7.3.1* ? because 7.3.11* brings me to this search result. normaly my coverage takes ~15min, now up to 40 min. :-( (debian + sury's updates: 7.3.11 + 2.8.0*)

Comment: @Derick - I'm now on Ubuntu 20 and PHP 7.4, so using XDebug 2.6 is no longer an option (as far as I know, haven't tested it yet) and I see the speed issues are still there :(

I'm stuck now, pages that would take 2 secs without a debugger now take 13 with xDebug and its pretty much unusable due to severe slow down.

Comment: XDebug is extremely slow when used with WordPress. From 1 second to load any page to 30 seconds! Inusable!